# getting the data between some time interval

Tags: python

what is th way to getting the data from the text file with some given time interval.

**search.txt**

```
19:00:00 ,  trakjkfsa,
19:00:00 ,  door,
19:00:00 ,  sweater,
19:00:00 ,  sweater,
19:00:00 ,  sweater,
19:00:00 ,  dis,
19:00:01 ,  not,
19:00:01 ,  nokia,
19:00:01 ,  collar,
19:00:01 ,  nokia,
19:00:01 ,  collar,
19:00:01 ,  gsm,
19:00:01 ,  sweater,
19:00:01 ,  sweater,
19:00:01 ,  gsm,
19:00:02 ,  gsm,
19:00:02 ,  show,
19:00:02 ,  wayfreyerv,
19:00:02 ,  door,
19:00:02 ,  collar,
19:00:02 ,  or,
19:00:02 ,  harman,
19:00:02 ,  women's,
19:00:02 ,  collar,
19:00:02 ,  sweater,
19:00:02 ,  head,
19:00:03 ,  womanw,
19:00:03 ,  com.shopclues.utils.k@42233ff0,
19:00:03 ,  samsu,
19:00:03 ,  adidas,
19:00:03 ,  collar,
19:00:04 ,  ambas,
```

i need to find out all the query between time 19:00:00 - 19:00:03
is there any way to find out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the builtin [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

```
import datetime as dt

t_start = dt.time(19,0,0)
t_end = dt.time(19,0,3)
with open('search.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        fields = [ x.strip() for x in line.split(',') ]
        timestamp = dt.datetime.strptime(fields[0], "%H:%M:%S").time()

        if t_start < timestamp < t_end:  # use "<=" if you want to search with boundaries included
            print fields[1],
```

This will print:

```
not nokia collar nokia collar gsm sweater sweater gsm gsm show wayfreyerv door collar or harman women's collar sweater head
```

Comment: @s_m your question there seems answered. If not, add comments to the answer that you've marked as the one that solves your problem.

Comment: can you look at that? and i have written some code but i don't think that seems on right way.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('search.txt')

start = '19:00:02'
end = '19:00:04'
queries = []     
line = file.read(10)         #read first 10 bytes

while start not in line:   #while the first 10 characters are not '19:00:02'
    file.readline()        
    line = file.read(10)

while end not in line:
    queries.append(file.readline().strip())
    line = file.read(10)

print queries
```

This reads the first 10 bytes of each line which contains every character up to the comma. If the  string `19:00:04` is not in the read string I append the rest of the line with `file.readline().strip()` to the `queries` list. This is done until the `search_for` time is read.

Comment: i am having a lot of line with time. so i think it will not work. is there any thing like that i can give the start time and end time till how it will find.?

Comment: if i want to start from 19:00:01 to 19:00:03 then what i will do?

Comment: Your question there is already answered. It's up to you to figure out what is going on in that answer. User `print` statements to see what each variable is.

Comment: I will see what I can do.

Comment: yea it could be. but i will get time by looping on that program. so i would not have knowledge of time at that time.